# Because local_auth >=1.1.0 <2.1.3 depends on intl ^0.17.0 and every version of flutter_localizations from sdk depends on intl 0.18.1

Tags: flutter, build-runner

[I am receiving the following error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yvje.png)

> Because local_auth >=1.1.0 <2.1.3 depends on intl ^0.17.0 and every
> version of flutter_localizations from sdk depends on intl 0.18.1,
> local_auth >=1.1.0 <2.1.3 is incompatible with   flutter_localizations
> from sdk. And because easy_localization >=3.0.0-nullsafety depends on
> flutter_localizations from sdk, local_auth >=1.1.0 <2.1.3 is
> incompatible with easy_localization >=3.0.0-nullsafety. So, because
> nelson_service_app depends on both easy_localization ^3.0.0 and
> local_auth ^1.1.8, version solving failed.

I used flutter upgrade

Comment: There is a mismatch between the lib local_auth and easy_localizations, they don't use the same version of intl. You need to find the corrects versions of the two packages who use the same version of intl.

Comment: Try upgrading `local_auth` version or downgrading `flutter`.